# How can I load an extensionless file in a Node JS application?

Tags: node.js, file, fs

I'm trying to load the `CONFIG` file from the `.git` folder of all of my repositories to parse the data manually and that particular file is extensionless. I'm trying to load it with `fs`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
function loadFile(filepath) {
    try {
        fs.readFile(filepath, function (exception, data) {
            if (exception)
                console.error(exception);
            else
                console.log(data.toString());
        });
    } catch (exception) {
        console.error(exception);
    }
}
```

However, when I put breakpoints in the `catch` block and the callback for `readFile`, none of them are hit.

---

How can I load an extensionless file in a Node JS application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you want to read does not need to have an extension,

Just give the correct path to Function.

For example, if the .git folder is next to your js file, you can read config like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function loadFile(filepath) {
    try {
        fs.readFile(filepath, function (exception, data) {
            if (exception)
                console.error(exception);
            else
                console.log(data.toString());
        });
    } catch (exception) {
        console.error(exception);
    }
}

loadFile('./.git/config')
```

Comment: I was using a full path instead of a relative one. Swapped to relative pathing and it works like a charm, thanks!